# Bower exit code #128 -

Tags: node.js, git, npm, bower-install

I tried to do npm cache clean and run "bower install" command. I get the following error:

```
bower ECMDERR       Failed to execute "git ls-remote --tags --heads git@github.xxx.com:myRelease/my-angular-logger.git", exit code of #128 Permissi
on denied (publickey). fatal: Could not read from remote repository.  Please mak
e sure you have the correct access rights and the repository exists.

Additional error details:
Permission denied (publickey).
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

I tried the following too:

> git config --global url."https://".insteadOf "git://

That also did not help. What might be the problem?

Thanks